# Setting up new Win7 computer without completing "First Boot" config

Tags: windows-7, boot, administrator, setup

Someone fairly technically challenged has asked me to set up their brand new computer by installing newest updates, antivirus, chrome browser, activate windows, etc. However, they still want to be prompted by the [Windows "First Boot" configuration screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jUxK.gif).

Is there any way I can login to the default Administrator account and perform these installations without creating another user? Or failing that, is there a way that I could delete the user I create and reset the flag that causes this screen to appear?

Rolling my own Windows installer is the absolute last resort.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After customizing the Windows installation you can put it back to the "ship to a customer" state by utilizing utility `sysprep`.

You will find the utility here: `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe`

More detailed description: [How Sysprep Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744512%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Most probably you will need `sysprep /oobe /shutdown`. Then after turning the computer on again the user will be presented by the initial setup including entering of the product key and activation. If you want to make the initial setup easier you can create an answer file - let's say Autoattend.xml. Here are details: [Walkthrough: Build a Simple Answer File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749317%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.
I ended up using Audit Mode (Ctrl+Shift+F3) mentioned in the link, which automatically launched a sysprep gui to let me put it back in OOBE Mode when I was done.